#  retrieved data from wordpress wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I just get item selected from this code that made by wp_dropdown_categories :

```
<select class="postform" id="cat" name="cat" size="8" multiple="multiple" style="margin-left: 5px; font-family: tahoma; width: 150px;">
    <option value="-1">select_option</option>
    <option value="7" class="level-0">vlc2</option>
</select>
```

and i use this code to get data from that multipile select box :

```
var terms = $('select#cat option:selected').text();
```

but when i alert it , data is contacted to themselves, like this :

```
terms=select_optionvlc2
```

and this is not that what i like , i want this :

```
terms=select_option,vl2
```

or

```
terms=[0] => select_option, [1]=>vlc2
```

awaiting for your ideas.

gracies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

    var term = $('#cat option:selected').map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).toArray().join(",");

    alert(term);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V6k6H/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":button").click(function(){
  var $arr=[];
  $("#cat option:selected").each(function(){    
    $arr.push($(this).text());
   });
alert($arr);                       
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LUSmA/4/

Comment: loops not recommended in client sides scripts like Jquery.thanks.